# IE10 - Iframe to xml to xsl file not displaying as in IE9

Tags: xslt

My page works in Chrome/Mozilla/IE9, but not in IE 10.

I have a .asp file that includes an .
iframe src = .xml file.
.xml file has this code

```
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test.xsl"?>
```

The .xsl file then has code to tell the browser how to format the xml data.

In IE9 everything is perfect.  In IE10 the iframe displays the xml data and ignores the xsl formatting.

Top of .xml file has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test.xsl"?>
```

Then all the data

Top of .xsl file has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Then all the formatting data

I tried adding this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

then this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

under the head tags, but no fix.

Any help would be appreciated.  The complete page code is lengthy which is why I didn't include it.